# Typesafe Activator: hello-slick tutorial adding an table input line gives Referential integrity constraint violation

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, h2, slick, typesafe-activator

I was using the Typesafe Activator to learn the Play Framework. I am in the `hello-slick` tutorial. I wanted to see if I could modify the code to add an additional line to the `coffees` table.

```
coffees += ("Test", 102, 7.99, 0, 0)
```

I have put the line before and after the block that inserts rows into the `coffees` table.

```
// Insert some coffees (using JDBC's batch insert feature)
val coffeesInsertResult: Option[Int] = coffees ++= Seq (
  ("Colombian",         101, 7.99, 0, 0),
  ("French_Roast",       49, 8.99, 0, 0),
  ("Espresso",          150, 9.99, 0, 0),
  ("Colombian_Decaf",   101, 8.99, 0, 0),
  ("French_Roast_Decaf", 49, 9.99, 0, 0)
)
```

The `coffees += ("Test"...` line creates the following error:

```
(run-main) org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "SUP_FK: PUBLIC.COFFEES FOREIGN KEY(SUP_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.SUPPLIERS(SUP_ID) (102)"; SQL statement: INSERT INTO "COFFEES" ("COF_NAME","SUP_ID","PRICE","SALES","TOTAL") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) [23506-170]
Referential integrity constraint violation: "SUP_FK: PUBLIC.COFFEES FOREIGN KEY(SUP_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.SUPPLIERS(SUP_ID) (102)"; SQL statement: INSERT INTO "COFFEES" ("COF_NAME","SUP_ID","PRICE","SALES","TOTAL") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) [23506-170]
Thread run-main exited.
Interrupting remaining threads (should be all daemons).
Sandboxed run complete..
Nonzero exit code: 1
(compile:runMain) Nonzero exit code: 1
Run complete.
```

Here is the code of the HelloSlick.scala file with the modification indicated by a comment:

```
import scala.slick.driver.H2Driver.simple._

// The main application
object HelloSlick extends App {

  // The query interface for the Suppliers table
  val suppliers: TableQuery[Suppliers] = TableQuery[Suppliers]

  // the query interface for the Coffees table
  val coffees: TableQuery[Coffees] = TableQuery[Coffees]

  // Create a connection (called a "session") to an in-memory H2 database
  Database.forURL("jdbc:h2:mem:hello", driver = "org.h2.Driver").withSession { implicit session =>

    // Create the schema by combining the DDLs for the Suppliers and Coffees tables using the query interfaces
    (suppliers.ddl ++ coffees.ddl).create


    /* Create / Insert */

    // Insert some suppliers
    suppliers += (101, "Acme, Inc.", "99 Market Street", "Groundsville", "CA", "95199")
    suppliers += (49, "Superior Coffee", "1 Party Place", "Mendocino", "CA", "95460")
    suppliers += (150, "The High Ground", "100 Coffee Lane", "Meadows", "CA", "93966")

    // MODIFICATION: add an extra line to the coffees table
    coffees += ("Test", 102, 7.99, 0, 0)

    // Insert some coffees (using JDBC's batch insert feature)
    val coffeesInsertResult: Option[Int] = coffees ++= Seq (
      ("Colombian",         101, 7.99, 0, 0),
      ("French_Roast",       49, 8.99, 0, 0),
      ("Espresso",          150, 9.99, 0, 0),
      ("Colombian_Decaf",   101, 8.99, 0, 0),
      ("French_Roast_Decaf", 49, 9.99, 0, 0)
    )

    val allSuppliers: List[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)] = suppliers.list

    // Print the number of rows inserted
    coffeesInsertResult foreach (numRows => println(s"Inserted $numRows rows into the Coffees table"))


    /* Read / Query / Select */

    // Print the SQL for the Coffees query
    println("Generated SQL for base Coffees query:\n" + coffees.selectStatement)

    // Query the Coffees table using a foreach and print each row
    coffees foreach { case (name, supID, price, sales, total) =>
      println("  " + name + "\t" + supID + "\t" + price + "\t" + sales + "\t" + total)
    }


    /* Filtering / Where */

    // Construct a query where the price of Coffees is > 9.0
    val filterQuery: Query[Coffees, (String, Int, Double, Int, Int)] = coffees.filter(_.price > 9.0)

    println("Generated SQL for filter query:\n" + filterQuery.selectStatement)

    // Execute the query
    println(filterQuery.list)


    /* Update */

    // Construct an update query with the sales column being the one to update
    val updateQuery: Query[Column[Int], Int] = coffees.map(_.sales)

    // Print the SQL for the Coffees update query
    println("Generated SQL for Coffees update:\n" + updateQuery.updateStatement)

    // Perform the update
    val numUpdatedRows = updateQuery.update(1)

    println(s"Updated $numUpdatedRows rows")


    /* Delete */

    // Construct a delete query that deletes coffees with a price less than 8.0
    val deleteQuery: Query[Coffees,(String, Int, Double, Int, Int)] = coffees.filter(_.price < 8.0)

    // Print the SQL for the Coffees delete query
    println("Generated SQL for Coffees delete:\n" + deleteQuery.deleteStatement)

    // Perform the delete
    val numDeletedRows = deleteQuery.delete

    println(s"Deleted $numDeletedRows rows")


    /* Selecting Specific Columns */

    // Construct a new coffees query that just selects the name
    val justNameQuery: Query[Column[String], String] = coffees.map(_.name)

    println("Generated SQL for query returning just the name:\n" + justNameQuery.selectStatement)

    // Execute the query
    println(justNameQuery.list)


    /* Sorting / Order By */

    val sortByPriceQuery: Query[Coffees, (String, Int, Double, Int, Int)] = coffees.sortBy(_.price)

    println("Generated SQL for query sorted by price:\n" + sortByPriceQuery.selectStatement)

    // Execute the query
    println(sortByPriceQuery.list)


    /* Query Composition */

    val composedQuery: Query[Column[String], String] = coffees.sortBy(_.name).take(3).filter(_.price > 9.0).map(_.name)

    println("Generated SQL for composed query:\n" + composedQuery.selectStatement)

    // Execute the composed query
    println(composedQuery.list)


    /* Joins */

    // Join the tables using the relationship defined in the Coffees table
    val joinQuery: Query[(Column[String], Column[String]), (String, String)] = for {
      c <- coffees if c.price > 9.0
      s <- c.supplier
    } yield (c.name, s.name)

    println("Generated SQL for the join query:\n" + joinQuery.selectStatement)

    // Print the rows which contain the coffee name and the supplier name
    println(joinQuery.list)


    /* Computed Values */

    // Create a new computed column that calculates the max price
    val maxPriceColumn: Column[Option[Double]] = coffees.map(_.price).max

    println("Generated SQL for max price column:\n" + maxPriceColumn.selectStatement)

    // Execute the computed value query
    println(maxPriceColumn.run)


    /* Manual SQL / String Interpolation */

    // Required import for the sql interpolator
    import scala.slick.jdbc.StaticQuery.interpolation

    // A value to insert into the statement
    val state = "CA"

    // Construct a SQL statement manually with an interpolated value
    val plainQuery = sql"select SUP_NAME from SUPPLIERS where STATE = $state".as[String]

    println("Generated SQL for plain query:\n" + plainQuery.getStatement)

    // Execute the query
    println(plainQuery.list)

  }
}
```

What is causing the error? Is there something wrong with adding data to the table in two separate ways?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the line to:

```
coffees += ("Test", 101, 7.99, 0, 0)
```

fixed the problem. I am guessing that the issue was not coming from the insertion of the row into the coffees table. It must be that the supplier I list for `Test` as `102` does not exist in the `suppliers` table.

The problem could also be fixed by adding:

```
suppliers += (102, "The Test Supplier", "100 Coffee Lane", "Meadows", "CA", "93966")
```

Indeed commenting out the following lines in the Tables.scala schema file and the corresponding Joins section in the HelloSlick.scala file fixes the problem as well.

```
def supplier: ForeignKeyQuery[Suppliers, (Int, String, String, String, String, String)] = 
  foreignKey("SUP_FK", supID, TableQuery[Suppliers])(_.id)
```